# Extend Camera Remote API for adjusting the focus

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

Could you please extend the Camera Remote API with some function to set and get the focus. This could be used for macro or landscape photography to allow taking pictures for focus stacking.
It would be great to have 4 additional calls to be able to implement taking pictures for focus stacking (e.g. for the Sony a7m3).

- setFocusPoint(xPosition, yPosition): Where x and y is the position corresponding to the the display of the camera
- getFocusPoint(): Get x and y
- setFocusDistance(distance): Where distance is specified in meter (float).
- getFocusDistance()

This way you could define a start and end point and how many pictures you want do end up, then calculate the steps in between to get several focus plains you can stack in post processing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not tech support for Sony, and therefor you can't file improvement requests here.

Comment: Mark, is there a way to file improvement requests elsewhere?

Comment: You'd need to contact Sony.

Comment: Aren't we doing exactly that here? :-)

Comment: No, Stack Overflow is not customer or technical support of Sony. See also [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not the place for feature requests to Sony.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are many focus options available to you using the Sony Camera Remote API The availability of these options will depend on the type of camera you use. You will also notice endpoints to check which options exist and which options are available. This is to first check to be sure your camera supports a particular option and then check to make sure that your camera is in a mode that supports that option. Here are all of the currently available focus endpoints:

- **setTouchAFPosition** : This API provides a function to enable touch AF and the position. : options - "Touch", Wide
- **getTouchAFPosition** : This API provides a function to get current touch AF position.
- **actTrackingFocus** : This API provides a function to start tracking focus. : options - "xPosition", "yPosition"
- **cancelTrackingFocus** : This API provides a function to cancel tracking focus.
- **setTrackingFocus** : This API provides a function to set a value of tracking focus setting. : Options- "On", "Off"
- **getTrackingFocus** : This API provides a function to get current tracking focus setting.
- **getSupportedTrackingFocus** : This API provides a function to get the supported tracking focus settings. The client should use "getAvailableTrackingFocus" to get the available parameters at the moment.
- **getAvailableTrackingFocus** : This API provides a function to get current tracking focus setting and the available tracking focus settings at the moment. The available parameters can be changed by user operations and calling APIs.
- **setFocusMode** : This API provides a function to set a value of focus mode. :  Options- "AF-S"
  Single AF
  "AF-C"
  Continuous AF
  "DMF"
  Direct Manual Focus
  "MF"
  Manual Focus
- **getFocusMode** : This API provides a function to get current focus mode.
- **getSupportedFocusMode** : This API provides a function to get the supported focus modes.
  The client should use "getAvailableFocusMode" to get the available parameters at the moment.
- **getAvailableFocusMode** : This API provides a function to get current focus mode and the available focus modes at the moment.
  The available parameters can be changed by user operations and calling APIs.

Unfortunately there is no current option to set focus distance.

Comment: Sadly setFocusDistance is the most wanted feature and on the a7iii there is missing much more … 1. It's Buggy, i cant use actTakePicture without Setting SelfTimer to 2sec or AF to ManualAF (even on the original playmemories app from sony). 2. getAvailableApi is not returning everything e.g. startLiveview (but it works) 3. setTouchAFPosition Returns an error, so does setSilentShutter. 4. There is no Information about the new Api Versions (1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8). Will does Things be added in the near future via Firmware update?

Comment: Sorry to hear about all of the issues. To answer your questions 1). for actTakePicture you should always first run getEvent to be sure the camera is not IDLE or in another improper state. 2). The currently available API list is dependent on the camera's current state. Try running getEvent to get more detailed information about what the API can do. 3). What type of error are you getting? 4). Unfortunately there is not a planned update scheduled for the Camera Remoate API

Comment: 1 The only Thing i could try is halfpressshutter before Shooting (will try as soon as possible) i got 40400 Shooting fail (same as playmemories app). 2. the available api list doesn't return startLiveView but i can call it. 3. for setTouchAfPosition return nosuchmethod (i'm not 100% sure but it doesn't work on playmemories app as well) 4. i think all sony users that do macros would love to set afdistance. Can you tell my why there are 4 new api versions but getMethodTypes Returns nosuchmethod?

Comment: Robert, Would it be possible to get support for setTouchAFPosition and getTouchAFPosition on the Sony A7 III, or is it just a bug that the methods don't work?

Comment: Unfortunately it is hard to say specifically why you are having an issue because all the supported cameras function differently. I actually don't see direct support for the A7 3 for auto focus, so it could be that your camera does not fully support it: https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/api-information/supported-features-and-compatible-cameras.  Although maybe it would be helpful to update the playmemories app and to update the firmware on your camera: https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=ILCE7RM3&LOC=3#/howtoTab

Comment: it both has the latest update but the camera seems to not yet have implemented the function or there's a bug. Would be nice to hear if someone is fixing this ...

Comment: ok I see. If you already have the latest updates then there is not anything else we can do to make the API work for your camera. It is very unfortunate, but your camera model does not have official support for these features and at this time we don't have an update planned. Are you able to use autofocus through the playmemories app?

Comment: No i'm not able on a7iii, it's also not possible to take a Picture (as i mentioned) without Setting to mf or to 2 sec self timer

Comment: Hi @Robert-Sony do we get any information if you want to fix those bugs? - Or is Sony not interested in customer experience?

Comment: We for sure want you to have a great experience with your camera, but unfortunately your camera does not seem to be on the supported list of cameras. I have actually heard many times about users being able to use the camera remote api without being on the supported list, but if the camera is not officially supported there is not much we can do in the way of making api calls work.

Comment: So your FLAGSHIP camera does not support remote control function? Whoever made this decision should leave your company - I hope I gonna find some users that can change your opinion and show how bad the user experience is.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again @Robert but I've gotta agree here, people are paying £3000 and up for the a9 and it doesn't support things (Touch AF, frame information e.t.c) that are supported on a £172.55 camera released 5 years ago (a5000)... it's frankly ridiculous that Sony think this is okay. Is there no line of communication we can open here between 3rd party devs and yourselves to discuss some of these issues!? I'm sure people would be willing to sit down and chat this through, and even help with development where they have knowledge of the issue and language in which the API is written!